# Submit button needs to be disabled permanently after sending emaiil and calling modal

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

This is my first question here. I am badly stuck in this particular area: I want to disable the 'Approve' button permanently ( only one button) which upon clicking sends an email (PHP)and calls a modal.
I learned here that I can achieve this through local storage but when I do so the button gets disabled instantly without performing any of the above mentioned tasks. please find the code for the button:

```
echo '<form action= "" method="POST" class="d-inline">';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value='.$row["request_id"].'>
          <input type="hidden" name="reqdate" value='.$str_d.'>
          <input type="hidden" name="rempid" value='.$row["r_emp_id"].'>
          <input type="hidden" name="rname" value='.$str_n.'>
          <input type="hidden" name="radvsal" value='.$row["advance_sal"].'>
          <button style="margin:5px; background-color:green;" class="btn mr-3" type="submit" name="Approve" value="Approve" id="Approve">Approve</button>';
```

And below are the codes when the button is pressed:

```
<?php   if(isset($_POST['Approve'])){
 // code for sending email
 mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); ?>
//calling modal  }?>
```

Comment: please try to use  <input type=submit ....>  instead of <button type=submit>xxx</button> and see the effect.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "permanently"? For the duration of the session? Literally forever for that one specific user? Also, how do you trigger your PHP action? Is it a normal submission or AJAX?

Comment: @El_Vanja: By permanently means for 2-3 days as the application goes for second approval, till then the button needs to be in disabled state. I am beginer level in  programming have used HTML, PHP and javascript and not AJAX.

Comment: That is a job for a database. If this is a business step, store the information that the user is currently on that step and then you can disable (or better yet, not show at all) the button (or an entire form or access to a page) based on that.

Comment: @El_Vanja: Do you mean to hide the button ?

Comment: Yes, you can disable or hide, whatever you prefer. But it should be based on a database value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in your conditional statement add this

```
<?php
$result = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($result) {        
$disabled = "disabled";
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     localStorage.setItem("approved", "yes");
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

then to your button add

```
echo "<button ".$disabled." type='submit' name='Approve' value='Approve' id='Approve'>";
```

then set a script that will check localstorage every time the user loads the page

```
if (localStorage.getItem("approved") != null) { 
   jQuery("#Approved").attr("disabled");
}
```

This will enable you to check the code after sent and on succeeding form / page visits